# bootstrap panel footer not parking where I'd expect

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Doing up a super-simple page, and I have a panel in the middle of the page as a way to delineate this information from other things. It's all working fine, except that I decided I wanted to add a panel-footer with some action buttons in it; that's when everything went to crap. I can either get the footer to flow without any explicit placement, or I can get it to park at the bottom of the page, but NOT at the bottom of the parent panel. I have no idea what's wrong, and would love a second set of eyes.

Disclaimer: I have a wicked cold and am on NyQuil - don't be surprised if I misspelled something :)

```css
.case-panel-footer-zz {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div style="border:3px solid blue; padding:10px;height:400px;">
  <!-- border so I can see what's up -->
  <div class="panel panel-default" style="height:60px;border:1px solid pink;">
    <!-- border so I can see what's up -->
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4>Select or create case</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body" id="caseSelector" style="border:1px solid green;">
      <span>the meaty center</span>
      <!-- empty during testing so as not to muddy the test-->
      <!-- I want to eventually resize this box to fit between header and footer, at 100%, padding factored, etc, yada yada yada -->
    </div>

    <div class="panel-footer case-panel-footer" style="height:60px;border:1px solid cyan;">
      <!-- border so I can see what's up -->
      <div>
        do the things
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary case-action-button" type="button" disabled="" data-action="select">Open case</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary case-action-button" type="button" data-action="new">Create new</button>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I guess this fiddle link will work. Save/public seems to be all screwed up.
https://jsfiddle.net/chornbe/7jfqea56/

Remove the "-z" from the css to apply the css and hit run.